# Why is my function not prompting me to enter input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

I’m using Python IDE 3. My goal is this: If I have a string of text, ‘ABCDEFGHIJKL’, I want to sort it into groups, like three groups (‘ADGJ’,’BEHK’,’CFIL’). I require input for this, but the prompts aren’t showing up and I can’t type in input. Here’s my code:

```
#data
code_text = input('Text: ').lower()
code_skip = int(input('Shift length: '))
code_list = []
#function
def countSkip(text, shift, listt):
    i = 0
    group = 1

    if group <= shift:
      for e in text:
#make sure the set starts at the right place
        if e.index()+1 < group:
          pass
        elif shift != 0:
          if i = shift:
            listt.append(e)
            i = 0
          i += 1
        else:
          listt.append(e)
          group += 1
```

## Calling the function

```
countSkip(code_text, code_shift, code_list)
```

Comment: Hmm, no, your code is not there.

Comment: Don’t name a variable 'list`, or `set`. Why are you defining a function inside another one?

Comment: `iterate` isn't recursive, so there's no point in defining it only to call it exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things stopping your code from working that people have pointed out in the comments. Instead of trying to dissect your code and get that to work, I wrote a much more concise function that will get you the results you're after

```
def text_splitter(input_text, set_length):
    num_sets = int(len(input_text)/set_length)
    split_text = ["".join([input_text[(n * num_sets) + m] for n in range(set_length)]) for m in range(num_sets)]
    return split_text

text_to_split = input('Text: ').lower()
len_set = int(input('Set Length: '))

text_list = text_splitter(text_to_split, len_set)
```

Sorry I was struggling to name the variables in an effective manner but the function above uses a list expression to get you the results you need. Keep in mind that if you use say a 7 letter string and ask for sets of length 2, the last letter won't be appended. However this shouldn't be too hard to check and correct. For example you could add this code to the function or around the initial input for the set length:

```
    while len(input_text) % set_length != 0:
        set_length = int(input("The text is length " + str(len(input_text)) + " please enter a different set length: "))
```

Comment: But why isn’t my code working? I fixed the issues pointed out in the comments but it still isn’t working.

Comment: @CariBerry there are quite a few things that are causing errors apart from that. you'd be best off trying to start from the beginning and think about it a bit more. The variable code_shift isn't defined. When you typed 'if e.index()+1 < group:' it would need to be text.index(e). You're appending everything into one list. You've defined one function inside another. There's more but what I'm trying to say is just give it another go and try a different approach. The method I used is a list expression and saves the need for 'for' 'if' loops in some cases